# Understanding why Element UI event handlers are triggering RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, element-ui

I'm currently attempting to set up a form and to validate it using Element UI. So far I have followed the documentation pretty closely, and it loads okay but once you click and type content into the input boxes, or click the submit form button it causes a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

I have attempted to go through and debug, and it seems to happen only on event triggers. In seems to go into all the validation functions properly when there is no input but once input is in, it is already stuck in the loop so I can't seem to get this part.

```
<template>
    <el-container class="card">
        <el-form ref="form" :model="form" :rules="rules" :label-position="labelPosition" size="small">
            <label>Username</label>
            <el-form-item size="small" prop="name">
                <el-input class="form-input" v-model="form.name"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
            <label>Password</label>
            <el-form-item prop="password" size="small">
                <el-input class="form-input" v-model="form.password" type="password"  autocomplete="off"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
            <el-form-item>
                <el-button class="form-button" type="primary" size="small" @click="submitForm('form')">Submit</el-button>
            </el-form-item>
        </el-form>
    </el-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "LoginPage",
        data () {
            let validateName = (rule, value, callback) => {
                if (value === '') {
                    callback(new Error('Please input valid username'));
                } else {
                    if (this.form.name !== '') {
                        this.$refs.form.validateField('name');
                    }
                    callback();
                }
            };
            let validatePassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
                if (value === '') {
                    callback(new Error('Please input valid password'));
                } else {
                    if (this.form.password !== '') {
                        this.$refs.form.validateField('password');
                    }
                    callback();
                }
            };
            return {
                labelPosition: 'top',
                form: {
                    name: '',
                    password: '',
                },
                rules: {
                    name: [
                        { validator: validateName, trigger: 'blur' },
                        { min: 2, max: 15, message: 'Length should be between 2 to 15', trigger: 'blur' }
                    ],
                    password: [
                        { validator: validatePassword, trigger: 'blur' }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submitForm(formName) {
                this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
                    if (valid) {
                        alert('yes');
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Examples of errors:

On button click with content in box: Error in event handler for "click": "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

On typing content into input box and clickin away: Error in event handler for "el.form.blur": "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [examples](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#custom-validation-rules) from the ElementUI documentation, you will see that they implement custom rules using `setTimeout` to throttle the number of times the rule will get called. In your case, as soon as the field has a value (ergo, the `if` case is false), your `else` block is getting executed over and over until it exceeds the maximum call stack size. You can fix this by throttling the calls to your custom rule like this:

```
export default {
  name: "LoginPage",
  data () {
    let validateName = (rule, value, callback) => {
      if (value === '') {
        return callback(new Error('Please input valid username'));
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.form.name !== '') {
          this.$refs.form.validateField('name');
        }
        callback();
      }, 1000);
    };
    let validatePassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
      if (value === '') {
        return callback(new Error('Please input valid password'));
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.form.password !== '') {
          this.$refs.form.validateField('password');
        }
        callback();
      }, 1000);
    };
    return {
      labelPosition: 'top',
      form: {
        name: '',
        password: '',
      },
      rules: {
        name: [
          { validator: validateName, trigger: 'blur' },
          { min: 2, max: 15, message: 'Length should be between 2 to 15', trigger: 'blur' }
        ],
        password: [
          { validator: validatePassword, trigger: 'blur' }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm(formName) {
      this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
          alert('yes');
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! That fixed it, thank you!

Comment: No problem -- glad I could help 